# Confused about Firebase query implementation

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to firebase and I need help with this please. I have two nodes in my database: users and posts as shown below:

```
users
    uid
      name: "William"
      post:
          KUhyPi5xLZBGyp-_X-W: true
         -KWH8EVxohgNBfHuKoYy: true

posts
    KUhyPi5xLZBGyp-_X-W     
                 comment: "I love this"
   -KWH8EVxohgNBfHuKoYy     
                 comment: "Coding is fun"
```

Currently I am able to display all the posts in tableView. But I want to be able to display the name of the user who made the post just like in facebook. Please advise me how to retrieve the username of who made a particular post at that indexpath so as to display it in a label in the tableViewcell

Here is code I am using to show all posts in the tableview currently

```
  DataService.ds.REF_POST.observe(
        .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot]{
                for snap in snapshot{
                    print("SNAP: \(snap)")
                    if let postDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{

                        let key = snap.key
                        let post = Post(postKey: key, postData: postDict)
                        self.posts.append(post)
                    }
                }
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
    })

}
```

Comment: You should get the name for the user from the uid node and then get the posts ids for that user as well.

Then do a separate query on the posts node to retrieve the different posts and match those posts to the post ids that you found in the uid node. Can you share some of your code?

Comment: @JordiBruin I have updated the codes in the question above as requested with code that I am currently using to populate the tableView

Comment: Is the use of the tableView to show users and their posts or is it to display posts and the users that posted them?

Answer (score 3):

When you save your comments, store the uid along with it so that you can easily query for it later.

```
{
    "posts" : {
        "KUhyPi5xLZBGyp-_X-W": {
            "uid": "USER_ID",
            "comment": "I love this"
        }
        "-KWH8EVxohgNBfHuKoYy": {
            "uid": "USER_ID",
            "comment": "Coding is fun"
        }
    }
}
```

I realise this looks like duplicating your data but this is how they recommend you store the data so that you can easily/quickly query it. For instance once you get all yoru comments you would then gather up all the user ids and go get those individual users. There isn't a way to do this all in one query.

Comment: I am still not too clear on how to implement it as you have advised.  Hope I am not asking for too much

Comment: Everytime you save a comment, store the userId.

Comment: Yes I have done that implementation already. I now have the posts save along side the uid,  Where I am having challenge is with retrieving the data for that user and appending it to the array that will populate the tableview